# Execution of a for loop

Tags: c, loops

How will this loop be executed infinite times?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    for (; scanf("%d", &i); printf("%d\n", i)); 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at the documentation of `scanf`, most notably the return value. (like, what is the behavior in case of an end-of-file ? in the case of an error ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Condition part of `for` loop is `scanf("%d", &i);` which return true until user provided invalid input . Read `man 3 scanf` and check return value.

Better run loop until you press key like `Ctrl+d`

```
for (; scanf("%d", &i) != EOF; printf("%d\n", i));
```

Or compare the return value of `scanf()`,as `scanf("%d", &i) == 1` returns `1` as long as it is able to convert user input into integer.

```
for (; scanf("%d", &i) == 1; printf("%d\n", i));
```

Comment: *"which always return true"* - Not always.

Comment: Except `EOF`, its true as even user given `0` `scanf()` returns `1`

Comment: The user can give any character. Most of them can't appear in an integer. For instance `.` is valid input, which can't be parse by `%d`.

Comment: yes you are right @StoryTeller I meant for integer input as OP use  `%d`.

Comment: yup.  Thanks again @chqrlie for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

That will run until `scanf` returns a zero value, so it could run forever so long as there's sufficient input. End-of-file will be zero.

This is a really ugly way of expressing that logic. Just use a `while`.

Actual files aren't infinite length, but there are things like the `yes` utility that produce endless streams of output that could be piped into a program like this.